# Specify cache expiry for com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory?

Tags: java, caching, dns, jndi

Struggling to find comprehensive documentation for JNDI and DNS. There is some [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jndi/jndi-dns.html) but it's rather limited.

Specific question: Is it possible to control the caching behaviour of lookups against DNS using `com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory`, for example to say 'do not cache'.

Example code:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "dns://mydns/mycompany.com");
....
DirContext ictx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

Additionally, is there some comprehensive API documentation that I haven't yet found?

Comment: have the same problem, networkaddress.cache.ttl doesn't affect DnsContextFactory - checked that using Wireshark